# Bootstrap tabs scroll effect to content when clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 Tabs like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
   <li><a href="#tab-1t" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab-3" data-toggle="tab"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Because the tab content gets quite long i want to add a scrolling effect that centers the tab content.

I am using this snippet for other scroll-effects on the site:

```
$('a.scroll').on('click', function(e){
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop:$(href).offset().top
},'slow');
e.preventDefault();
});
```

When i add the "scroll" class to the tab links i get the desired effect but only on already active tabs. With inactive tabs it requires two clicks.

What should i change?

UPDATE:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t5Wk6/2/)

Comment: Can you add a http://jsfiddle.net demo?

Comment: See updated main question..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle, Now its working fine

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/t5Wk6/3/)**

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('.nav a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  })  

  $('a.scroll').on('click', function (e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
      }, 'slow');
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

```
// scroll to top action
$('.nav-tabs li a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'fast'); 
    $(this).tab('show');    
});
```