# Jquery tabs scroll to content when click on tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

This is starting to test me a little bit now. I have a set of Jquery Tabs using the UI version 1.10.

```
        $('#tabs').tabs();

<ul>
<li><a href="#id1">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#id2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="id1">Content in here</div>
<div id="id2">Content in here</a>
```

Simple tab structure. Because the links have a # in the href, when you click on the tab menu it jumps you down just below the mnenu of the tabs to the content. I need to stop this from happening and just staying where it's clicked..

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle to show us more what you mean?

Comment: It's a bootstrap issue, but still no resolution. This article says they have a fix but the jsfiddle does the same thing I'm seeing.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088649/bootstrap-tabs-scroll-effect-to-content-when-clicked

http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/t5Wk6/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding this code it stopped the scrolling.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Code to stop scrolling to tab content
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        $('.ui-tabs-anchor').click(function (evt) {
           // stops from submitting the form
           evt.preventDefault();
           return false;
        }); 

      });
      //Code to stop scrolling to tab content
        $('.ui-tabs-anchor a').bind('click',function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
        });
        enter code here
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check the solution below. I removed the href's content and added onclick event for each and every tab.

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>


<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#tabs div').hide(); $('#tabs-1').fadeIn(800); ">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#tabs div').hide(); $('#tabs-2').fadeIn(800); ">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('#tabs div').hide(); $('#tabs-3').fadeIn(800); ">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I have narrowed it down to a bootstrap issue.

Comment: @CreativeFlair If this didn't work for you instead of editing this answer with what worked for you post your own new answer.

Comment: I posted the answer that works perfectly alright for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the jquery UI css?

If you have included the css, I think the final result would look like the below example, and the page would stop jumping to the anchor link.

```
example:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9nStn/

Comment: I have added the jquery css. It's part of a Drupal site so I removed all styles and added just a UI theme and it worked. I've narrowed it down to a bootstrap issue.