# Bootstrap 4, how to auto-scroll to opened tab content?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, tabs

When viewing my page on a mobile phone, the user clicks on a tab and has no way to know it opened since it is down below and requires scrolling to see it.

When a user clicks the tab, I would like it to auto-scroll to the open content.

I've tried following the solution here but am unable to get it to work for my specific page:
[Bootstrap tabs scroll effect to content when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21088649/bootstrap-tabs-scroll-effect-to-content-when-clicked?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Tim

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
  })

  $('a.scroll').on('click', function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 'slow');
    e.preventDefault();
  });




});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<section class="ftco-section ftco-schedule" id="schedule-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center pb-5">
      <div class="col-md-12 heading-section text-center ftco-animate">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ftco-schedule">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 nav-link-wrap">
          <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">

            <a class="nav-link ftco-animate" id="v-pills-9-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-9" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-9" aria-selected="false">Tuesday <span>Muay Thai & Mixed Martial Arts</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link ftco-animate" id="v-pills-10-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-10" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-10" aria-selected="false">Wednesday <span>Muay Thai & Mixed Martial Arts</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link ftco-animate" id="v-pills-11-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-11" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-11" aria-selected="false">Thursday <span>Muay Thai, Mixed Martial Arts & Boxing</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link ftco-animate" id="v-pills-13-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-13" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-13" aria-selected="false">Saturday <span>Muay Thai</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 tab-wrap">

          <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">

            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-8-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <i class="far fa-hand-point-left fa-4x"></i>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <h2>Click to see the schedule</h2>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-9" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-9-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">6:45PM - 7:30PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Muay Thai Kickboxing</a></h2>
                  <p>In attition to learning brutally effective kicking, punching, elbow and knee techniques, you can expect a great workout from this fun class.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">Muay Thai Instructor</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">7:30PM - 8:15PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Mixed Martial Arts (MMA)</a></h2>
                  <p>This comprehensive class teaches the fundamentals as well as the advanced techniques of MMA. </p>
                  <p> Erik Paulson's Combat Submission Wrestling (CSW) will also be taught. </p>
                  <p>Beginner to Professional levels are welcome.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">MMA Coach</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-10" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-10-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/roy-eubank-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">6:45PM - 7:30PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Muay Thai Kickboxing</a></h2>
                  <p>In attition to learning brutally effective kicking, punching, elbow and knee techniques, you can expect a great workout from this fun class.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Roy Eubank</a> <span class="position">Muay Thai Instructor</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/roy-eubank-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">7:30PM - 8:15PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Mixed Martial Arts (MMA)</a></h2>
                  <p>This comprehensive class teaches the fundamentals as well as the advanced techniques of MMA. </p>
                  <p>Erik Paulson's Combat Submission Wrestling (CSW) will also be taught. </p>
                  <p>Beginner to Professional levels are welcome.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Roy Eubank</a> <span class="position">MMA Coach</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-11" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-11-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">6:45PM - 7:30PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Muay Thai Kickboxing</a></h2>
                  <p>In attition to learning brutally effective kicking, punching, elbow and knee techniques, you can expect a great workout from this fun class.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">Muay Thai Instructor</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">7:30PM - 8:15PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Mixed Martial Arts (MMA)</a></h2>
                  <p>This comprehensive class teaches the fundamentals as well as the advanced techniques of MMA. </p>
                  <p>Erik Paulson's Combat Submission Wrestling (CSW) will also be taught. </p>
                  <p>Beginner to Professional levels are welcome.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">MMA Coach</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/pat-swan-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">7:15PM - 8:15PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Boxing</a></h2>
                  <p>All experience levels are welcome to attend this class taught by professional boxer, Pat Swan. </p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Pat Swan</a> <span class="position">Boxing Coach</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-13" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-13-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">12:00PM - 12:45PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Muay Thai Kickboxing</a></h2>
                  <p>In addition to learning brutally effective kicking, punching, elbow and knee techniques, you can expect a great workout from this fun class.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">Muay Thai Instructor</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 Accordian scroll to open content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570191/bootstrap-4-accordian-scroll-to-open-content)

Comment: @SaiManoj I see that it's very similar and I tried to use your javascript, but I'm not knowledgeable enough with javascript to get the proper edits made to apply it to the html code in this example. Thank you.

Comment: No issues, Happy learning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`shown.bs.tab`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#events) event

> This event fires on tab show after a tab has been shown. Use
>   event.target and event.relatedTarget to target the active tab and the
>   previous active tab (if available) respectively.

```js
$('a.nav-link').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<section class="ftco-section ftco-schedule" id="schedule-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center pb-5">
      <div class="col-md-12 heading-section text-center ftco-animate">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ftco-schedule">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 nav-link-wrap">
          <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">

            <a class="nav-link ftco-animate" id="v-pills-9-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-9" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-9" aria-selected="false">Tuesday <span>Muay Thai & Mixed Martial Arts</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link ftco-animate" id="v-pills-10-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-10" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-10" aria-selected="false">Wednesday <span>Muay Thai & Mixed Martial Arts</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link ftco-animate" id="v-pills-11-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-11" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-11" aria-selected="false">Thursday <span>Muay Thai, Mixed Martial Arts & Boxing</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link ftco-animate" id="v-pills-13-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-13" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-13" aria-selected="false">Saturday <span>Muay Thai</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 tab-wrap">

          <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">

            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-8-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <i class="far fa-hand-point-left fa-4x"></i>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <h2>Click to see the schedule</h2>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-9" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-9-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">6:45PM - 7:30PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Muay Thai Kickboxing</a></h2>
                  <p>In attition to learning brutally effective kicking, punching, elbow and knee techniques, you can expect a great workout from this fun class.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">Muay Thai Instructor</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">7:30PM - 8:15PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Mixed Martial Arts (MMA)</a></h2>
                  <p>This comprehensive class teaches the fundamentals as well as the advanced techniques of MMA. </p>
                  <p> Erik Paulson's Combat Submission Wrestling (CSW) will also be taught. </p>
                  <p>Beginner to Professional levels are welcome.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">MMA Coach</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-10" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-10-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/roy-eubank-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">6:45PM - 7:30PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Muay Thai Kickboxing</a></h2>
                  <p>In attition to learning brutally effective kicking, punching, elbow and knee techniques, you can expect a great workout from this fun class.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Roy Eubank</a> <span class="position">Muay Thai Instructor</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/roy-eubank-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">7:30PM - 8:15PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Mixed Martial Arts (MMA)</a></h2>
                  <p>This comprehensive class teaches the fundamentals as well as the advanced techniques of MMA. </p>
                  <p>Erik Paulson's Combat Submission Wrestling (CSW) will also be taught. </p>
                  <p>Beginner to Professional levels are welcome.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Roy Eubank</a> <span class="position">MMA Coach</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-11" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-11-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">6:45PM - 7:30PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Muay Thai Kickboxing</a></h2>
                  <p>In attition to learning brutally effective kicking, punching, elbow and knee techniques, you can expect a great workout from this fun class.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">Muay Thai Instructor</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">7:30PM - 8:15PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Mixed Martial Arts (MMA)</a></h2>
                  <p>This comprehensive class teaches the fundamentals as well as the advanced techniques of MMA. </p>
                  <p>Erik Paulson's Combat Submission Wrestling (CSW) will also be taught. </p>
                  <p>Beginner to Professional levels are welcome.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">MMA Coach</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/pat-swan-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">7:15PM - 8:15PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Boxing</a></h2>
                  <p>All experience levels are welcome to attend this class taught by professional boxer, Pat Swan. </p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Pat Swan</a> <span class="position">Boxing Coach</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-13" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-13-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">12:00PM - 12:45PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Muay Thai Kickboxing</a></h2>
                  <p>In addition to learning brutally effective kicking, punching, elbow and knee techniques, you can expect a great workout from this fun class.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">Muay Thai Instructor</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add scroll animation inside a `setTimeout` and click on `a.nav-link` instead of `a.scroll`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).tab('show')
  })

  $('a.nav-link').on('click', function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(href + '.active').offset().top
      }, 'slow');
    }, 500);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<section class="ftco-section ftco-schedule" id="schedule-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center pb-5">
      <div class="col-md-12 heading-section text-center ftco-animate">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ftco-schedule">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 nav-link-wrap">
          <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">

            <a class="nav-link ftco-animate" id="v-pills-9-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-9" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-9" aria-selected="false">Tuesday <span>Muay Thai & Mixed Martial Arts</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link ftco-animate" id="v-pills-10-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-10" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-10" aria-selected="false">Wednesday <span>Muay Thai & Mixed Martial Arts</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link ftco-animate" id="v-pills-11-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-11" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-11" aria-selected="false">Thursday <span>Muay Thai, Mixed Martial Arts & Boxing</span></a>
            <a class="nav-link ftco-animate" id="v-pills-13-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-13" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-13" aria-selected="false">Saturday <span>Muay Thai</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 tab-wrap">

          <div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">

            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-8" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-8-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <i class="far fa-hand-point-left fa-4x"></i>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <h2>Click to see the schedule</h2>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-9" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-9-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">6:45PM - 7:30PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Muay Thai Kickboxing</a></h2>
                  <p>In attition to learning brutally effective kicking, punching, elbow and knee techniques, you can expect a great workout from this fun class.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">Muay Thai Instructor</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">7:30PM - 8:15PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Mixed Martial Arts (MMA)</a></h2>
                  <p>This comprehensive class teaches the fundamentals as well as the advanced techniques of MMA. </p>
                  <p> Erik Paulson's Combat Submission Wrestling (CSW) will also be taught. </p>
                  <p>Beginner to Professional levels are welcome.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">MMA Coach</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-10" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-10-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/roy-eubank-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">6:45PM - 7:30PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Muay Thai Kickboxing</a></h2>
                  <p>In attition to learning brutally effective kicking, punching, elbow and knee techniques, you can expect a great workout from this fun class.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Roy Eubank</a> <span class="position">Muay Thai Instructor</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/roy-eubank-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">7:30PM - 8:15PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Mixed Martial Arts (MMA)</a></h2>
                  <p>This comprehensive class teaches the fundamentals as well as the advanced techniques of MMA. </p>
                  <p>Erik Paulson's Combat Submission Wrestling (CSW) will also be taught. </p>
                  <p>Beginner to Professional levels are welcome.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Roy Eubank</a> <span class="position">MMA Coach</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-11" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-11-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">6:45PM - 7:30PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Muay Thai Kickboxing</a></h2>
                  <p>In attition to learning brutally effective kicking, punching, elbow and knee techniques, you can expect a great workout from this fun class.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">Muay Thai Instructor</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">7:30PM - 8:15PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Mixed Martial Arts (MMA)</a></h2>
                  <p>This comprehensive class teaches the fundamentals as well as the advanced techniques of MMA. </p>
                  <p>Erik Paulson's Combat Submission Wrestling (CSW) will also be taught. </p>
                  <p>Beginner to Professional levels are welcome.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">MMA Coach</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/pat-swan-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">7:15PM - 8:15PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Boxing</a></h2>
                  <p>All experience levels are welcome to attend this class taught by professional boxer, Pat Swan. </p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Pat Swan</a> <span class="position">Boxing Coach</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-13" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-day-13-tab">
              <div class="coach-wrap ftco-animate d-sm-flex">
                <div class="img coach-img" style="background-image: url(/images/tim-mousel-profile.jpg);"></div>
                <div class="text pl-md-5">
                  <span class="time">12:00PM - 12:45PM</span>
                  <h2><a href="#">Muay Thai Kickboxing</a></h2>
                  <p>In addition to learning brutally effective kicking, punching, elbow and knee techniques, you can expect a great workout from this fun class.</p>
                  <h3 class="coach-name">&mdash; <a href="instruct.php">Tim Mousel</a> <span class="position">Muay Thai Instructor</span></h3>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you Om, that works perfectly. I selected the answer based on who answered first correctly, otherwise I would have chose yours. Thank you!

Comment: No problem @TimM. Thank you for your upvote. I appreciate it.